# Can anyone confirm this hadith?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

> Whoever reads Surah Al-Kahf on Friday ALLAH will bless his house and
> protect him/her from poverty.

is this statement true or found in hadith? please tell me. cause i haven't found any hadith.

Comment: And where did you get this?

Comment: I know that there is a story in Surah kahf. Maybe what you are talking about comes from that?